# Share posts from Websites into twitter

Tags: twitter

Thanks in Advance . Here am trying twitter share functionality ..How to do that in codeigniter

```
<div> <p>Post description</p><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></div>
```

While i am click this icon it has to share particular post to twitter . How to do that .

Answer (score 0):

> Pass Only this url to share any type of post or page

```
<div> <p>Post description</p> <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?php echo current_url(); ?>&text=Your Post Title"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></div>
```